# Parallel plane retrieval from chessboard with pose in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, camera, homography, ransac

I'm using OpenCV on Python3, and I'd like to get the positions of the corners of a chessboard with dimensions `pattern_size` on a plane parallel to the one of a chessboard that I have at disposition, vertically displaced by a certain value `fdz` (in chessboard side units).
In order to achieve that, I modified the pose algorithm that can be found in https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d53/tutorial_py_pose.html in this way:

```
function vertical(img,pattern_size, corners, camera_matrix, dist_coefs,fdz):

    objp = np.zeros((pattern_size[1]*pattern_size[0],3), np.float32)
    objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:pattern_size[0],0:pattern_size[1]].T.reshape(-1,2)

    a = []
    for j in range(pattern_size[1]):
        for i in range(pattern_size[0]):
            axis = np.float32([[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [i,j,-fdz]]).reshape(-1,3)

            # Find the rotation and translation vectors.
            _, rvecs, tvecs, inliers = cv2.solvePnPRansac(objp, corners, camera_matrix, dist_coefs)

            # project 3D points to image plane
            imgpts, jac = cv2.projectPoints(axis, rvecs, tvecs, camera_matrix, dist_coefs)
            imgpts = np.array(imgpts)
            a.append(imgpts[2].ravel())
            # draw circles on points found
            cv2.circle(pose, (imgpts[2].ravel()[0], imgpts[2].ravel()[1]), 5, (0,255,0), -1)

    cv2.imwrite('./pose.jpg', pose)

return(a)
```

This works for some images ([original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsnYr.jpg)), while for some others it does this trick:
[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iy6fH.jpg).
Do you have any suggestions on the problem? My best guess is that I didn't still completely understood how `cv2.solvePnPRansac` and `cv2.projectPoints` work.

EDIT

I did find out that the problems are due to the RANSAC algorithm: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTXgO.jpg) you can see the results of applying `cv2.solvePnP` instead of `cv2.solvePnPRansac` to the same image as before; however, this appears to happen only with angles between the chessboard and the camera normals bigger than a certain threshold, below which the script works fine.

However, the results with and without the RANSAC step are slightly different, so it would be probably useful to try and include it.
Do you have an idea on why this happens? Is there a way to control the parameters of the RANSAC in the algorithm?

Comment: could it be that the "corners" point is detected in those problematic images in a different order? When you pass the corners and obj points to the solve pnp, they must match to each other, if a point does not match it may be removed by the ransac algorithm, but if the order is around it may give you a rotation of 180°... I think project points may only give weird results if the points are behind the camera (I do not remember if it was opencv or another library that had this behaviour)

Comment: @api55 I checked it, and in effect the order of the 'corners' array is different from image to image; do you have any suggestion on how to sort it? I could even rotate all the output points, but that seems quite cumbersome

Comment: I had once this problem, however in my case it was enough to know the relation of the first and last point... for instance if the first point x was greater than the last point then I revert the order...  another way is that this images should have high reprojection error... and you can invert them and do it again....

Comment: @api55 Crazily enough, I did find out that the problem is given by the RANSAC part of the algorithm: it seems that for big enough angles between the camera and the chessboard normals, something goes wrong (see the edit of the question); do you have any suggestions on why that happens?

Comment: Well, it could be that the RANSAC algorithm selects only some points and overfits to them.... Your results look quite bad (with a lot of differences), is this one with the correct order of the points or with different order? I think it can get a lot better

Comment: @api55 I checked the order and it is right, the only thing that changes between [the first output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iy6fH.jpg) and [the second output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTXgO.jpg) is that the former uses cv2.solvePnPRansac while the second one cv2.solvePnP.
This solves my problem (I will use cv2.solvePnP, without RANSAC), but it would be maybe useful to find a way to act on the RANSAC part of the algorithm.